# Cleanup after TerminateThread?

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I free the virtual memory that is left up after calling `TerminateThread`? Can it be done via `VirtualFree` and how of course. I fully understand the **"Dangers"** of `TerminateThread`.

Comment: No, you can't. That's the side effect of TerminateThread

Comment: @Matt In Vista+ the virtual memory is cleaned up. So I am talking about XP and before.

Comment: The best you can do after calling `TerminateThread` is to also close the handle to it - at least allow the thread object to be deleted. But for allocated memory (and thread stack up to Windows XP and server 2003) are definitive memory leaks until process termination.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Unless you *know exactly* what memory was only used by the thread and is safe to reclaim. Which is only slightly less likely than a safe call to `TerminateThread` in the first case!

Comment: @Deduplicator You can get start address from the thread and the stack it's using.

Comment: @JohnLewis: But can you also *guarantee* that none of that memory is still in use?

Comment: @Deduplicator If its a leak? Who else does it belong to?

Comment: That *is* the question... and in general, it's really hard.

Comment: @Deduplicator : I was thinking about memory allocated in the thread with a pointer in thread stack (and only in thread stack). But I agree with you, we cannot ask the system to know where are the pointers to allocated memory ! (unless using cli and its gc but that would be a different question ...)

Comment: *In Vista+ the virtual memory is cleaned up.* That's not true.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Vista DOES indeed free the stack.

Comment: @JohnLewis That's nice. What about all the other memory allocated by the thread?

Comment: As for the stack on XP and earlier, there's this: http://www.nicklowe.org/2012/01/thread-termination-dont-leak-the-stack/

Comment: Cleaning up memory is the least of your worries when calling `TerminateThread`. I'd be more concerned about global locks being held, eventually leading to a deadlock (e.g. the global lock used to serialize heap allocations). The answer is simple: Don't call `TerminateThread` or stop worrying about your application's health.

Comment: @IInspectable Depends on the situation really.

Comment: Uhm.... it doesn't depend on **anything**. Either don't play russian roulette, or stop caring about the outcome.

Comment: @IInspectable Obviously its not a universal solution. I never looked for one in the quesion.

Comment: Please take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here you can read about the dangers of calling TerminateThread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an unmanaged process, there's no realistic way to tidy up memory from the outside.

Memory can be allocated in many different ways. Ultimately it all starts with calls to `VirtualAlloc`, `VirtualAllocEx` etc. But in practice runtime libraries invariably use sub allocating heap managers. These heap allocators will get memory by calls to `VirtualAlloc`, but then will hand out sub-blocks. And heap managers are generally shared between threads in a process. So you've no way from the outside of knowing how to free those sub-blocks.

And even if we did not have sub-allocators, how could you know which blocks handed out by `VirtualAlloc` you were allowed to destroy? A thread may allocate memory with a call to `VirtualAlloc` and require that  the memory out lives the allocating thread and is destroyed by another thread.

But if you are happy to let all of that go, and just want the stack to be destroyed (as per your comments), then this article shows you how to do so with `RtlFreeUserThreadStack`: http://www.nicklowe.org/2012/01/thread-termination-dont-leak-the-stack/

Comment: Pretty likely that you are missing the point of the question.  Threads do not own VirtualAlloc-ed address space, the process does.  Except one detail, the stack space allocated for the thread by CreateThread().  Which is indeed released automatically in Vista+ but not in earlier versions.

Comment: @HansPassant What's the point of releasing the stack and leaving everything else? And threads own the stack, yes. But processes own the threads. So ultimately the processes own the stack too.

Comment: Getting rid of the address space leak of course.  There is no "everything else" that can't be released.

Comment: @HansPassant Getting rid of some of the address space leak. Not all of it.